# Binary Encoding vs One-hot Encoding

Tags: machine-learning, neural-networks, classification, categorical-encoding

What is the difference between binary encoding and one-hot for categorical input variables for English Text and their impact on the neural network?
Can anyone help me to find a scientific paper about this problem?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

If you have a system with $n$ different (ordered) states, the binary encoding of a given state is simply it's $\text{rank number} - 1$ in binary format (e.g. for the $k$th state the binary $k - 1$). The one hot encoding of this $k$th state will be a vector/series of length $n$ with a single high bit (1) at the $k$th place, and all the other bits are low (0).

As an example encodings for the next system (levels of education):

| Level | "Decimal encoding" | Binary encoding | One hot encoding |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| No | 0 | 000 | 000001 |
| Primary | 1 | 001 | 000010 |
| Secondary | 2 | 010 | 000100 |
| BSc/BA | 3 | 011 | 001000 |
| MSc/MA | 4 | 100 | 010000 |
| PhD | 5 | 101 | 100000 |

References: [One hot encoding at Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/One-hot)

And a 2017 paper on the comparison on the effects of different encodings to neural networks in the International Journal of Computer Applications could be a good starting point:
[A Comparative Study of Categorical Variable Encoding Techniques for Neural Network Classifiers](https://www.researchgate.net/profile/Kedar_Potdar/publication/320465713_A_Comparative_Study_of_Categorical_Variable_Encoding_Techniques_for_Neural_Network_Classifiers/links/59e6f9554585151e5465859c/A-Comparative-Study-of-Categorical-Variable-Encoding-Techniques-for-Neural-Network-Classifiers.pdf)

Comment: Thank you very much but for level of character

Comment: What do you mean by "but for level of character"? Sorry, I don't get it.

Comment: when make the pre-processing of data(encoding) to enter the model  we represent each character to zeros and ones not word

Comment: if you find any research paper talks about this thanks in advance

Comment: Also, if you have $n$ unique categories (or words here), OHE results in either $n$ or $n-1$ features where as binary encoding results in only $\log_{2} n$. So if your vocabulary is $100$ words then OHE needs at least $99$ features whereas binary encoding needs only $7$ which is a major reduction in dimensionality.

Comment: I just read this paper: https://www.diva-portal.org/smash/get/diva2:1259073/FULLTEXT01.pdf Unsuprisingly, one-hot encoded variables give the best precision. I think it's a good practice to only use binary encoding when we are limited by resources.